# Finding the right selector to alter wordpress theme css code

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress theme and am trying to find the correct selector from the browser element inspector to alter the css code.

my website is http://randomship.com and the element i'm looking to alter is:

```
<div class="sticky-wrapper" style="height: 1px">
```

This element is the small 1px strip at the very top of the page. I'm trying to change the height to none/0px.

So far i've tried:

```
div .sticky-wrapper {height: none; }
```

FYI: this is for a child theme.

Thanks!

Comment: Just remove the inline style from the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Inline styles have more weight than other styles. You'll need `!important`:

```
div.sticky-wrapper { height: 0 !important; }
```